# Jetty 9: Static files для виртуального хоста

Tags: java, jetty

Здравствуйте, 
По этой доке www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configur... добавил site1.xml в папку /usr/share/jetty9/webapps

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war">/home/user/sites/site1/ROOT.war</Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>site1.com</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

А как расшарить папку со статическими файлами (много всего, фото юзеров, и т.д.)?

Можно создать папку static_content в /usr/share/jetty9/webapps, но она видна будет всем хостам. Вроде простой такой вопрос а не найду решения.

Comment: напишите сервлет, который юзает эту папку, а затем дайте разрешения отдельным юзерам на скачивание контента.